# Give a complement of $U \cap V$ in $U + V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Hey I have the following exercise where I am having a problem. Can someone help me?

Consider the following vectors in the$ \mathbb{R}$ vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$: $v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}, v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},v_3 =\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},v_4 =\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Let $U = <v_1, v_2>$ and $V = <v_3, v_4>$.

(a) Determine a basis of $U$, of $V$ , of $U \cap V$ and of $U + V$ .

b)Give a complement of $U \cap V$ in $U + V$.

a) So here I found the basis of $U \cap V=<\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}>$
and for $U+V=<\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}>$ (If you want you can check the results but they should be right)

For b) I really don't know how to proceed.
What is asked is to find two vectors that are not in the basis of $U \cap V$ that added to the basis of $U \cap V$ gives a basis of $U+V$, right?

How can I do it?

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Right.  And you already have a basis of $U+V$. Can you use some of those vectors?

Comment: Can I Just do a row reduction of this matrix? $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 2 & -1 & 1  \\ 1 & 1 & 2  \\ 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{matrix}\right)$

At the end I have $\left(\begin{matrix} 2 & -1 & 1  \\ 0 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2}  \\ 0 & 0 & 2  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ and this gives me the vectors on the 2. and 3. rows. Is it right? @RobertIsrael

Comment: It's even simpler than that.  Take any vector that's in $U$ but not $V$, and any vector that's in $V$ but not $U$. Can you see why?

Comment: I am sorry but no :( @RobertIsrael

Comment: $U+V$ has dimension $3$, so any $3$ vectors that span it will be a basis.